# Parse.com localized errors

Tags: ios, parse-platform, localization, nserror

So I'm trying to find a way to localize errors from Parse.com in my iOS app, there's one post from two years ago where the solution is to take a look at "PFConstants.h" in Parse framework but there's only the codes for the errors and not their description (https://www.parse.com/questions/localized-error-description).
Plus, using [error userInfo] returns this on my UIAlertView:

[image]

Otherwise, If I use [error localizedDescription]:

[image]

Any idea on how can I translate the errors according to their codes?

Answer (score -1):

A possible issue could be the end point. Looking at the number of /2/user_login is referring to version 2 of the API which I don't see as being available. Looking at all the end points when I login the api version is showing as /1/ and instead of user_login the api reference is showing just login. So from what I can see it should be https://api.parse.com/1/login . If you want to test copy this https://username:password@api.parse.com/1/login into the browser and hit enter.  It will pop up a username and password box. You will not be able to login because you can't specify your application information so it has not way to validate your login.

Comment: Oh no, I forced this error by trying to login without internet connection, what I want to do is to get "The internet connection appears to be offline." and access parse errors to be able to translate them into Spanish

Comment: I should have realized that by the localize, sorry was a late night last night. Let me get back to you on this one.